# using segmented control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

okay i have a tabbed view, so two view controllers. in one view controller i have a segmented control and to know which segment was selected i have an action connected to it. like this:

```
-(IBAction)selectAngle:(id)sender{
    clickedSegment = [myAngleType selectedSegmentIndex];
}
```

here `clickedSegment` is an integer which i have exposed as a property in my header. now i want to use the value of this `clickedSegment` in my other view controller but whenever i create an instance of that VC(segmented controller one) and try to use `clickedSegment`, i always get 0 as the value no matter if i selected other segment 1 or 2. its always zero. where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is your second view controller going to know about any property in the first view controller? This is impossible, unless you explicitly get a reference to it.

```
// in second view controller
FirstViewController *firstVC = 
   (FirstViewController*)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"clicked segment: %d", firstVC.clickedSegment); // assuming int
```

Comment: firstly thanks a lot! but i got a quick question, why didnt this work? ...FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];...and then just use firstVC.clickedSegment?

Comment: and i have imported the firstVC in my header.

Comment: Because you have to reference the active view controller, not create a new instance. Logically, the new instance will have all attributes empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the synthesized setter correctly, you should set it like this:

```
-(IBAction)selectAngle:(id)sender{
    self.clickedSegment = [myAngleType selectedSegmentIndex];
}
```

Comment: yep did that but still clickedSegment is zero in the first VC, i took a log of value and it does get changed but then i go to other tab and no change! zero!-_-